# How to combine structs in go for network devices?

Tags: go, inheritance, data-structures, struct, composition

I am trying to implement a structure (in a kind of capturing program) for keeping network devices' list in golang. Each device-type both have some basic network attributes (which are applicable to all devices), and also have device specific attributes. In this case I am confused about how to implement this structure without inheritance. I am trying to make a composition of structs, but I am stuck with the following two ways:

**Approach A:**

```
type baseDevice struct { //Base device data that every device has one
    address byte
    mac     byte
}

type lightDevice struct { //The device specific fields
    state      bool
    brightness byte
    device     baseDevice
}

type relayDevice struct { //The device specific fields
    state     bool
    momentary byte
    device    baseDevice
}
```

**Approach B:**

(I'm not sure if this is applicable)

```
type baseDevice struct { //One single device struct
    address byte
    mac     byte
    deviceType //And gets the device-specific device type struct
}

type lightDevice struct {
    state      bool
    brightness byte
}

type relayDevice struct {
    state     bool
    momentary bool
}
```

The first approach seems like the better way to implement. But the problem is, the data streamed in chunks and all the chunks don't have the device type. So, first I capture the devices as a typeless (generic) device. Then, when I capture the device-type data, I parse the rest of the data according to the device type.

In this case what is the correct way to implement?

Comment: Approach A is better as at does not use generic type. Thus making your program faster

Answer (score 0):

Go can do it similar to inheritance.As follows, `lightDevice` can use the properties of `baseDevice`

```
type baseDevice struct { //Base device data that every device has one
    address byte
    mac     byte
}

type lightDevice struct { //The device specific fields
    baseDevice
    state      bool
    brightness byte
}

type relayDevice struct { //The device specific fields
    baseDevice
    state     bool
    momentary byte
}
```